# Selenium Find element inside row

Tags: python, selenium, browser, automation

**HTML:**

```html
<table id="wanInstTable_tbl" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="alignment_rule">
      <td><input style="width:null" class="NewDelbuttoncss" id="Newbutton" type="button" value="New" onclick="clickAdd('wanInstTable_head');"><input style="margin-left:9px;width:null" id="DeleteButton" class="NewDelbuttoncss" type="button" value="Delete"
          onclick="OnDeleteButtonClick('wanInstTable_head');"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="button_spread"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="wanInstTable_head">
        <table width="100%" class="tabal_bg" id="wanInstTable" cellspacing="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="head_title">
              <td class="" id="headwanInstTable_0_0"></td>
              <td class="align_center restrict_dir_ltr" id="headwanInstTable_0_1">Connection Name</td>
              <td class="align_center" id="headwanInstTable_0_2">VLAN/Priority</td>
              <td class="align_center" id="headwanInstTable_0_3">Protocol Type</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="wanInstTable_record_no" class="tabal_01">
              <td align="center" class="" id="wanInstTable_0_0">--</td>
              <td align="center" class="align_center restrict_dir_ltr" id="wanInstTable_0_1">--</td>
              <td align="center" class="align_center" id="wanInstTable_0_2">--</td>
              <td align="center" class="align_center" id="wanInstTable_0_3">--</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I read this [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):, but can't do it.

I need acces to `id=Newbutton` to `first Tr` to `firs td` is a `button` `clickable`, I've been trying everything for a long time

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not shared the code that you've tried and what is the exact error stack trace, I can probably assume few things.

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//input[@class='NewDelbuttoncss' and @id='Newbutton' and @value='New' and contains(@onclick,'clickAdd')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This div is not under an iframe.
2. This div is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

to click on it, You can use the below code trials :

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='NewDelbuttoncss' and @id='Newbutton' and @value='New' and contains(@onclick,'clickAdd')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='NewDelbuttoncss' and @id='Newbutton' and @value='New' and contains(@onclick,'clickAdd')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='NewDelbuttoncss' and @id='Newbutton' and @value='New' and contains(@onclick,'clickAdd')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='NewDelbuttoncss' and @id='Newbutton' and @value='New' and contains(@onclick,'clickAdd')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, I can see that Chrome indicates and marks the XPath correctly, but it still does not press the button with the options you provided. Below I attach all the HTML.